# navigation bar is visible when i navigate back to main view

Tags: iphone, xcode, uinavigationcontroller

i am using this in my view didlod
[self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:YES];
it hides when applicationn launches but when i navigate to next screen and come back to main view is not hide it navigation bar...
why is it like that?

should i add any thing ?

....

Comment: You're missing a few tags. Let's start with: what platform is this for?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This works for me:

```
- (void) viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];    
    [self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:YES animated:animated];
} 

- (void) viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewWillDisappear:animated];
    [self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:NO animated:animated];
}
```

You wouldn't then need the one in viewDidLoad.

If it's not clear from that change, the reason your original code didn't work is that the view may be kept in memory even if it is not on screen - so need to hide / display the navigation bar each time the view is brought on or off screen.

Comment: i want to add back ground image to navigation controller root view 
i am using 
 self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage: [UIImage imageNamed:@"background.png"]]; 
its not working

Comment: Glad it's working! You should ask your background image question as a new question so more people see it.

Comment: k i will add it
but when use your methods to hide navigation bar ,its giving space to move my  table view upside ,but i dont want to move up and i should able add image in place of navigation bar ...
thanks for that help. in advance..

Comment: can u provide a syntax to add image in place of nav bar

Answer (score 0):

viewDidLoad only fires the first time it loads your view.  viewWillAppear fires every time.